# scanf fails to add data to a struct?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm writing a program to add two vectors, I've defined two structs like so:

```
typedef struct TwoDVector {
    float x_coord;
    float y_coord;
} vec_2d;

typedef struct VectorAddData {
    float x_coord;
    float y_coord;
    float magnitude;
} vec_data;
```

Then in my code I run a loop to add data:

```
vec_data add_vectors(vec_2d vec1, vec_2d vec2) {
    vec_data final_vec;
    final_vec.x_coord = vec1.x_coord + vec2.x_coord;
    final_vec.y_coord = vec1.y_coord + vec2.y_coord;
    final_vec.magnitude = sqrt(pow(final_vec.x_coord, 2) + pow(final_vec.y_coord, 2));

    return final_vec;
}

int main(void){
    while (1) {
        int choice;
        printf("Press 1 to add two vectors(2D)\nPress 0 to quit: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1) {
            vec_2d vec1, vec2;
            vec_2d arr[] = {vec1, vec2};
            for(int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
                printf("Enter values for vector %d\n", i + 1);
                printf("Enter x_coord for vector %d: ", i + 1);
                scanf_s("%f", &arr[i].x_coord);
                printf("Enter y_coord for vector %d: ", i + 1);
                scanf_s("%f", &arr[i].y_coord);
            }
            printf("\nAdding the 2 vectors...\nVec1 = %fi + %fj \t vec2 = %fi + %fj\n", vec1.x_coord, vec1.y_coord, vec2.x_coord, vec2.y_coord);
            vec_data final_vec = add_vectors(vec1, vec2);
            printf("Addition of 2 vectors = %fi + %fj\n", final_vec.x_coord, final_vec.y_coord);
            printf("Magnitude of final vector: %f\n", final_vec.magnitude);

        } else if (choice == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid input!");
        }
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

But as I enter values, the code only returns x and y coordinates as 0.000, what am I doing wrong, I've written this code standalone before.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result. It is not productive to debug incomplete code snippets. For example you don't even show  the full `add_vectors` function including what it returns.

Comment: The error occurs before i can even reach the add_vectors functions, the scanf_s is not adding the value to the coordinates. Regardless I'm updating the question. Thanks

Comment: That's even more confusing. Please just provide a [mre].

Comment: You are printing `vec1` and `vec2` instead of the array elements. The array elements and `vec1`, `vec2` are different variables. You scan into the array elements but prints the two other variables

Comment: I have updated the question with the full code.

Comment: `vec_2d arr[] = {vec1, vec2};` Are you thinking that the `arr` is referring to the original `vec1` and `vec2`? That's not the case. It initialises the array with a copy of the (unintialised) data in `vec1` and `vec2`.

Comment: Again here: `vec_data final_vec = add_vectors(vec1, vec2)` You use `vec1, vec2` but that is not where you data is... It should be `add_vectors(arr[0], arr[1]);`

Comment: Why do you have `vec1, vec2` ? Delete them and just do: `vec_2d arr[2];`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you're putting the values into arr but reading from vec1, vec2

when you do vec_2d arr[] = {vec1, vec2}; you're copying the values from vec1, vec2 into a new array called arr.
If you want arr to point to vec1 and vec2 you should do:

```
vec_2d *arr[] = {&vec1, &vec2};
```

and then:

```
printf("Enter x_coord for vector %d: ", i + 1);
scanf_s("%f", &arr[i]->x_coord);
printf("Enter y_coord for vector %d: ", i + 1);
scanf_s("%f", &arr[i]->y_coord);
```

Comment: `&arr[i]->x_coord` hmmm...did you try that? I don't think so

Comment: @SupportUkraine yeah I did. It works. I prefer to put parentheses for readability but it works at it is now

Comment: Really? `error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'vec_2d' {aka 'struct TwoDVector'})
   15 | scanf("%f", &arr[0]->x_coord);`

Comment: It's obvious from the error that arr[0] is vec_2d while it should be vec_2d *.
Also, pls look at this https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence . you can see here that -> and [] come before &.

Comment: Why do you go on claiming that this works when it is obviously wrong? See https://ideone.com/M3teM5

Comment: @SupportUkraine you're still doing the same error. you need to use vec_2d *arr[] instead of vec_2d arr[]

Comment: @SupportUkraine here is my code https://ideone.com/TBItWa. I expect an apology and a thumbs up